# Why do I get "ValueError: too many values to unpack" when running this program?

Tags: python

```
#  *kwargs for variable number of keyword arguments:
def my_function(**Kwargs):
    for key, value in Kwargs:
        print("%s == %s" % (key, value))


my_function(first='fruits', second='vegetable', third='flowers')
```

It is giving error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aadi\PycharmProjects New\functionin python\main.py", line 163, in <module>
    my_function(first='fruits', second='vegetable', third='flowers')
  File "C:\Users\Aadi\PycharmProjects New\functionin python\main.py", line 159, in my_function
    for key, value in Kwargs:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: 1. It's a `ValueError`, not a `SyntaxError`, 2. `Kwargs` iterates over keys. Try `Kwargs.items()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterating over a `dict` yields only the keys. You need to iterate over the key/value pairs yielded by the `items` method:

```
for key, value in Kwargs.items():
```

Comment: Thank you body for help me .Thanks a lot